# Multi level category in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

The content category of my site is multi-level. I have designed a table with the following columns to manage it:

```
Id
Name
ParentId
```

And at the time of adding the category, I register the parent id in the parent id field and everything is fine

Now, when adding content, I want to have a list of category names as follows:

```
Category 1 > Level 1 Child > Level 2 Child > Level 3 Child
Category 2 > child level 1
Category 3 > Child Level 1 > Child Level 2
```

Comment: Hello.  You need to be more clear as to what it is that you need help with.  You described the scenario so far.  What is the problem?